# CAT APIs suddenly stopped working for elasticsearch on my nodes

Tags: elasticsearch

CAT APIs suddenly stopped working for elasticsearch on my nodes. All other APIs are working. Cluster is healthy too.

Restarted the elastic process too.

It's pretty weird. Any idea why is this happening ?

No response for this:

```
curl -XGET localhost:9200/_cat/nodes
```

Gives response for this:

```
$ curl -XGET localhost:9200/_cat/
=^.^=
/_cat/allocation
/_cat/shards
/_cat/shards/{index}
/_cat/master
/_cat/nodes
/_cat/indices
/_cat/indices/{index}
/_cat/segments
/_cat/segments/{index}
/_cat/count
/_cat/count/{index}
/_cat/recovery
/_cat/recovery/{index}
/_cat/health
/_cat/pending_tasks
/_cat/aliases
/_cat/aliases/{alias}
/_cat/thread_pool
/_cat/plugins
/_cat/fielddata
/_cat/fielddata/{fields}
```

Comment: What's the response you get ?

Comment: no response. Just hangs.

Comment: I'm on a pretty old version too. v1.4

Comment: "No response" probably means the response takes a longer time to get back.

Comment: How big is your cluster? and yes, 1.4 is pretty old, you should consider upgrading at some point

Comment: Cluster is pretty big. About 100 nodes.

Comment: Yeah, indeed. that's probably why `_cat/nodes` takes a long time to return an answer.